# Usage of tryCatch function

Tags: r, try-catch

I would like to use the `trycatch` function in R to check if the given value is an integer if not return ERROR. My current code looks the following, it doesnt work.

```
 b <- function() as.integer(n_top_features)
  tryCatch ( {
    error = function(e){
      b()
    }
  },
    stop('ERROR: n_top_features variable should be integer!')
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [documentation of the `tryCatch` function](https://rdrr.io/r/base/conditions.html), you see the following usage:

```
tryCatch(expr, ..., finally)
```

That is: the actual expression you want to “try” is the first argument, and the *handlers* (which you’ve attempted to write) come afterwards:

```
tryCatch(
    as.integer(n_top_features),
    error = function (e) {
        stop('ERROR: n_top_features variable should be integer!')
    }
)
```

However, that won’t work either; and the reason is that `as.integer` does not raise an error when the argument can’t be converted to an integer. It raises a *warning* instead. So your `tryCatch` needs to install a *warning* handler:

```
result = tryCatch(
    as.integer(n_top_features),
    warning = function (w) {
        stop('ERROR: n_top_features variable should be integer!')
    }
)
```